# Merge two values into single value using a merge algorithm in Java

Tags: java, xml, merge

Need help to perform merge two similar contact values. 
I would like to know how can i merge two similar contact values into a single contact  before I convert it as a xml file using Java.
In my case I have contacts like this:

```
Contact No1:
Contact
Arun
Arun_niit
nuraaa_iceee@yahoo.co.in
Contact
Contact No2:
Contact
Arun
Arun_niit
nuraaa_iceee@gmail.com
Contact
```

Contact No1&2 has same name and also the contact No 3&4

```
Contact No3:
Contact
Rangarajkarthik
karthik Rangaraj
kart26@gmail.com
karthikranga@yahoo.com
Contact


Contact No4:
Contact
Rangaraj
karthik 
kart26@gmail.com
karthikranga@yahoo.com
Contact
```

The above contact repeating twice with the same name and email address. How can I merge this as a single contact?

This is my .partf file and I want to convert this to an XML file which I did. But I want to merge these contacts and then create a XML using my JavaCode.

```
Contact
Arun
Arun_niit
nuraaa_iceee@yahoo.co.in
Contact
Contact
ColomboGiorgia
Giorgia Colombo
giorgiacolombo81239@libero.it
Contact
Contact
Arun
Arun_niit
nuraaa_iceee@gmail.com
Contact
Contact
KumarVeera
Veera Kumar
KUMARg_8111@yahoo.com
Contact
Contact
MarbellaFunkybuddha
Funkybuddha Marbella
http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=1123301493096451
Contact
Contact
Rangarajkarthik
karthik Rangaraj
kart2006@gmail.com
karthikrangaraj@yahoo.com
Contact
Contact
Rangaraj
karthik 
kart26@gmail.com
karthikranga@yahoo.com
Contact
```

My JavaCode:

```
package textparser;  
import java.io.BufferedReader;
  import java.io.FileOutputStream;
  import java.io.FileReader;
  import java.util.regex.Pattern;
  import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;
  import java.io.Serializable;
  import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.OutputFormat;
  import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.XMLSerializer;
  import com.sun.xml.internal.bind.util.AttributesImpl;
  public class Item  {
  public static void main (String args[]) {
  Item.readWrite("D:/Demo/test.part","D:/Demo/juin202.xml");//Read XML and Save as a XML file.
  }

  public static void readWrite(String fromFile, String toFile)  
  {
try{
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".+@.+\\.[a-z]+");//A compiled representation of a regular expression. 
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fromFile));
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(toFile);
    OutputFormat of = new OutputFormat("XML","windows-1250",true);//Codepage Windows-1250 - Character Code Listing for Central Europe languages.
    of.setIndent(1);
    of.setIndenting(true);//JDOM API:This will set the indent String to use; this is usually a String of empty spaces.
    XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer(fos,of);
    ContentHandler hd = serializer.asContentHandler();//The Serializer interface is implemented by a serializer to enable users to: get an org.xml.sax.ContentHandler or a DOMSerializer to provide input to. 
    hd.startDocument();
    AttributesImpl atts = new AttributesImpl();//Construct a new, empty AttributesImpl object.
    hd.startElement("","","CONTACTS",atts);//To create root tag <Contacts>
    String line = null,tag;
    while ((line=in.readLine())!=null) {
        if(line.equals("Contact")){
            line=in.readLine();
            hd.startElement("","","CONTACT",atts);
            int i=0;
            while(!line.equals("Contact")){
                if(i==0)
                    tag="FirstName";
                else if(i==1)
                    tag="LastName";
                else{
                    if(p.matcher(line).matches())
                        tag="EMail";
                    else
                        tag="URL";
                }
                hd.startElement("","",tag,atts);
                hd.characters(line.toCharArray(),0,line.length());
                hd.endElement("","",tag);
                i++;
                line=in.readLine();
            }
            hd.endElement("","","CONTACT");
        }
    }
    hd.endElement("","","CONTACTS");
    hd.endDocument();
    fos.close();
    System.out.println("Work is done and check your file specified in the directory");
    in.close();
    }catch(Exception E){
        System.out.println("Cannot Generate XML!!!");
            }

        }
  }
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems simple, as you load your contacts compare the contact you are loading to what you have already loaded.  If it is a duplicate, you don't really need to merge you just need to delete (or just stop loading) the duplicate contact.

Comment: Did you see in Contact 1&2 has the same names but two different emails. I think in this case i can't delete! i can go for merge all values.

Comment: You said you wanted to merge 3&4 but did not say that for 1&2.  If you want to merge both cases you are going to either decide which email to choose or somehow include them both.  But if the emails are different how do you know it is not two different people with the same name.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. I agree with your question but some how I want to make this function to merge same names with different values.

Comment: When the email addresses are different how do you want to merge them?  Take the first? Combine the two into a single string?

Comment: Ok, but how can i take a the email value of contact no 2 and put in contact no 1, if both Contacts has a same name?

Comment: Save the items in memory as you load them.  Add the email address from 2 to 1 when you load 2 and see that it is a match.

Comment: @karthikrangaraj let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2130/discussion-between-jzd-and-karthik-rangaraj)

Answer (score 1):

I did not look into your code in detail, but I think you have a more general design problem. You should 1) read the file and store each of the different contacts in an Object, for now let's call it `InputContact`. 2) you must specify your rules for merging the contacts. 3) iterate over the list of `InputContact`s and perform the comparisons and build a new list of `MergedContacts`.